# C++ SSE and aligned array of ints and vector of ints

Tags: c++, vector, sse, memory-alignment

Thanks to some of you, I have already used SSE for speeding up computation of one of my function of my scientific app in [C++ use SSE instructions for comparing huge vectors of ints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791892/c-use-sse-instructions-for-comparing-huge-vectors-of-ints).

The final version of the optimized SSE function is:

```
int getBestDiffsSse(int nodeId, const vector<int> &goalNodeIdTemp) {
    int positionNodeId = 2 * nodeId * nof;
    int myNewIndex = 2 * nof;
    int result[4] __attribute__((aligned(16))) = {0};

    __m128i vresult = _mm_set1_epi32(0);
    __m128i v1, v2, vmax;

    for (int k = 0; k < myNewIndex; k += 4) {
        v1 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *) & distances[positionNodeId + k]);
        v2 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *) & goalNodeIdTemp[k]);
        v1 = _mm_xor_si128(v1, vke);
        v2 = _mm_xor_si128(v2, vko);
        v1 = _mm_sub_epi32(v1, vke);
        v2 = _mm_sub_epi32(v2, vko);
        vmax = _mm_add_epi32(v1, v2);
        vresult = _mm_max_epi32(vresult, vmax);
    }
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i *) result, vresult);
    return max(max(max(result[0], result[1]), result[2]), result[3]);
}
```

where

```
const __m128i vke = _mm_set_epi32(0, -1, 0, -1);
const __m128i vko = _mm_set_epi32(-1, 0, -1, 0);
```

and

```
int* distances 
distances= new int[size];
```

where size is huge (18M x 64)

My naive question is: Do you believe I could get a better speed up if both: a) array distances is aligned or b) vector goalNodeIdTemp is aligned and 
c) how do I do that?

I' ve seen some posts about memalign or align_malloc but I have not understand how to use them for a dynamic array or a vector. Or since I am talking about ints, alignment is not an issue? Keep in mind I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and gcc, so a solution about Visual Studio compiler is not an option.

Added questions: First of all, is the following code enough to align the dynamic array (Keep in mind that definition and initialization have to be kept differently);

```
int *distances __attribute__((aligned(16)));
distances = new int[size];
```

Second, in order to align vector goalNodeIdTemp do I need to write entire code for custom vector allocator? Is there a simpler alternative?

I need your help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you can do to improve performances a bit :

- take `__m128i v1, v2, vmax;` out of the loop, but that is most likely done by the compiler
- make sure distances is properly aligned
- instead of using std::vector, align data and pass the pointer. Then use `_mm_load_si128`.

If distance and goalNodeIdTemp were properly aligned, you could use raw pointers. Something like this :

```
__m128i *v1 = (__m128i *) & distances[positionNodeId + k];
__m128i *v2 = (__m128i *) & goalNodeIdTemp[k];
```

All further optimizations, you need to look into assembly code.

---

> Do you believe I could get a better speed up if both: a) array distances is aligned b) vector goalNodeIdTemp is aligned

Yes, you will get a small performance boost. Nothing spectacular, but if every cycle count, then it may be noticeable

> how do I do that?

To have `goalNodeIdTemp` aligned, you have to use a special allocator for `std::vector` (see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942548/making-stdvector-allocate-aligned-memory) how to do it).

To align `distance`, you have to be a bit careful. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973995/dynamic-aligned-memory-allocation-in-c11) how to allocate aligned memory.

Comment: a) is done b) (make sure distances is properly aligned) I do not know how to do that (this is the original question) c) I also do not know how to do that

Comment: @AlexandrosE. Ok, sorry. I missed those questions. I'll edit my answer